# kill syscommand yields a failure in Catch2 test case

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test, catch2

I'm using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) for testing in C++. My test case forks a child process and at some point the parent process sends a `kill(pid, SIGTERM)` to it to clean it up.

However, I get the following error from Catch2.

```
FAILED:
due to a fatal error condition:
  SIGTERM - Termination request signal
```

Of course I'm deliberately making this sys call so I don't consider it a test fail. How can I get Catch2 to ignore this failure condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable POSIX signal handling by defining `CATCH_CONFIG_NO_POSIX_SIGNALS` during compilation.